# In quantum mechanics when we use the real wavefunctions to find the average value of momentum operator then it comes out be zero. What does it mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

In quantum mechanics when we use the real wavefunctions to find the average value of momentum operator then it comes out be zero. What does it signifies? Please explain it.

Comment: You can show this using the definition of hermitian conjugate for the momentum operator. A related fact: eigenstates of a particle in a scalar potential can be represented by real wave functions.

Answer (score 2):

$\langle p\rangle=0 $ simply means that on average there is no change in momentum, or (by Ehrenfest’s theorem) no change in $m\langle v\rangle$.  This is automatic if the *probability density* is time-independent since any average value will also be time-independent, but $\langle v\rangle = \frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle$.

In solving the time-independent Schrodinger equation, one can often choose a real wavefunction $\psi(x)$.  The full time dependent solution is then
$\psi(x)e^{-itE/\hbar}$.  The probability density for this solution is $\vert\psi(x)\vert^2$ and independent of time; thus for instance $\langle x\rangle$ does not depend on $t$.

Now to momentum: the average momentum is just $m\langle v\rangle = m\frac{d\langle x\rangle}{dt}$, but you have $\langle x\rangle$ independent of $t$ and thus $d\langle x\rangle/dt=0$: since the probability density does not depend on $t$, the average $\langle x\rangle$ does not depend on $t$ and thus $\langle p\rangle$ is $0$ since it involves a derivative w/r to $t$ of $\langle x\rangle$.

This does not depend on $\psi(x)$ being real: the probability density is also real if you use $i\psi(x)$ since $\vert i\psi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}\vert^2=\vert\psi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}\vert^2=\vert\psi(x)\vert^2$ even if $i\psi(x)$ is pure imaginary if $\psi(x)$ is real.

If $\psi(x)$ is real, there is also a direct (but overly narrow) way to see this: since $\hat p\mapsto i\hbar d/dx$ is an observable, its average value $\int dx \psi^* \left(i \hbar d\psi(x)/dx\right)$ would necessarily be pure imaginary unless it were the real number $0$.

The situation changes as soon as your probability density depends on $t$.  For instance, if your wavefunction is $\alpha \psi_1(x)e^{-iE_1t/\hbar}+\beta\psi_2(x)e^{-iE_2t/\hbar}$, then the probability density will have a time-dependent factor of the form $\cos(\omega_{12}t+\varphi)$, where $\omega_{12}=(E_1-E_2)/\hbar$, even if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real.  In this case, the probability density does depend on $t$, $\langle x\rangle$ does depend on $t$, and $\langle p\rangle\ne 0$.

Thus the key is not so much the “real wavefunction” but rather if the probability density is real (for all times).   For eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian, the probability density for the full solution will always be time-independent, but for combination of full solutions, like $\alpha e^{-iE_1t/\hbar}+\beta e^{-iE_2t/\hbar}$, the probability density always depends on $t$ unless $E_1=E_2$.

Answer (score 0):

You know how to integrate a wave function and its conjugate along with the momentum operator, to find the expectation value, I hope. The proof to show that expectation value of p = 0 for real wave functions, is a little more complex, so I'll try to explain using words. For a real wave function, there is no imaginary part in it, and so, its hermitian conjugate is equal to itself. Basically f(x)*=f(x), if f(x) is the wave function. I suggest you go a plug such wave functions into your integral, and you'll find out

=0 for all cases, except when the wave function is complex. I don't think there is a massive physical significance behind this, more like a mathematical property. I can explain the physical significance of

=0, though. This means, particles have equal probability of moving left or right i.e. equal likely to have velocity v or -v.

Summarizing, what you have pointed out is nothing more than a fact, that you can verify by doing the math. There is no special physical significance behind it, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a particle in a $1D$ box of width $L$, with infinite potential walls; the wave functions are:

$$\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{L}}\sin{\dfrac{n\pi}{L}}x$$

The momentum operator is:

$$\hat{p}=-i\hbar \partial_x$$

The expectation (average) value of momentum over the entire box's domain is given by:

$$\langle p \rangle=\int_0^L \psi^*(x) \hat{p}(x)\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

This is simple enough to calculate and indeed yields $0$.

> **What does it signifies? Please explain it.**

So that means that the average velocity $\langle v \rangle$ is zero. And of course that's the correct outcome: the particle can 'move' (in that weird quantum way) inside its box but **it can never escape, so its net velocity must be zero.**

Answer (score 0):

$$\langle p \rangle = \int\!d^3x\, \psi^* (-i \partial_x)\psi = ({\rm by\;parts})\; \int\!d^3x\, \psi\, i\partial\psi^* = (\psi=\psi^*)\; \int\!d^3x \psi^* (i \partial_x)\psi = -\langle p \rangle = 0$$

Basically, what this means is that if a wave function is real, that means it's fourier transform is even in momentum, $\psi(-p) = \psi(p)$, and hence $\langle p \rangle =0$.